# React.js deal with missing data in json (TypeError: Cannot read property 'prefix' of null)

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I read an API but the json result is not always "complete". In line 2 the age is missing.

```
 {
     ["name": "Max", "age":15, "country": 1],
     ["name": "Muster", "country": 56],
     ["name": "Test", "age": 5, "country": 5]
 }
```

When I try to map over the array I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'age' of null)

```
{items.map((res, index) => (
    <p>
        {res.name}
        {res.age}
        {res.country}
     </p>
))}
```

What is the best way to deal with missing data in the JSON response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if property exits or not: 
{res.age ?  res.age : ''}

Comment: Thank you, this is working! But the code will become very ugly if I have to check every variable before render it

Answer (score 0):

Below structure of data looks weird :

```
{
     ["name": "Max", "age":15, "country": 1],
     ["name": "Muster", "country": 56],
     ["name": "Test", "age": 5, "country": 5]
}
```

But, You can use a `safe operator` for that :

```
 {res?.age ?? ''} // empty string will be returned in case res == null or undefined
```

**WORKING DEMO** :

[image: Edit so-react-safe-operator]

Comment: Thank you for the example. I tried it in the real code but its not working. It gives me "Syntax error: Unexpected token" The real code is much more nested then the example ( {res.LineType_product.lineType.suffix?.name_short} )